# React Rails - Component not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've gone as far as I can

I am using the react gem for rails

```
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.3.0'
```

and I hope to have a React loop

```
<%= react_component( "Posts", { posts: @posts} )%>
```

I have a post.js.jsx file in assets/javascripts/components with:

```
var Posts = React.createClass({
    render(){
        var createItem = ({article}) => <Post post={article} />;
        console.log(this.props.posts);
        return <div>{this.props.posts.map(createItem)}</div>;
    }
});
```

I require the article from each post to be in the view - however it won't return and the console.log does return an array of objects of the this.props.posts (it is also passing the @ instance variable to the data tag of the react_component tag in the source of the page.

Trying to understand why I can't gain access to "article" and why it is saying I have Posts undefined error in the console log.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Post is not defined
```

Comment: You have this error because you haven't defined the Post class. There must be `var Post = React.createClass({....` somewhere in your code.

Comment: I thought var Posts = React.createClass does that but that I guess is the component name?

Comment: They're all just classes. You're calling Post class, so you have to define Post class. Posts != Post and Posts doesn't automatically define Post.

Comment: where can I declare it in React? I thought jsx would convert `<Post post={article} />;` to `<div>my article text</div>`